# Question about proof ot Tychonoff's theorem for metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Tychonoff's theorem: The cartesian product $M = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}M_i$ is compact $\iff$ each $M_i$ is compact.

My book, before proving it, says that the proof will happen like this:

Given an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ in $M$, lets prove that it has a convergent subsequence. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $x_n=(x_{n1}, x_{n2}, \cdots, x_{ni}, \cdots)$. We'll obtain an infinite subset $\mathbb{N}^*\subset N$ such that for each $i$ there exists $\lim_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}x_{ni}=a_i\in M_i$. Then, by saying $a=(a_1,a_2, a_3, \cdots)\in M$ we have $\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}x_n = a$.

My question is: what is $x_n=(x_{n1}, x_{n2}, \cdots, x_{ni}, \cdots)$? How can, for each $n$, be defined a sequence like this? Can you give me an example of such sequence?

Later, in the proof, it picks $M_1$ compact and say that the sequence $(x_{11}, x_{21}, \cdots, x_{n1}, \cdots$ has a convergent subsequence. This made me think that the book is picking a sequence in each $M_i$, and that each of those sequences is different, that is, he could say that the sequence for $M_1$ would be $(a_n)$, for $M_2$ would be $(b_n)$, for $M_3$ would be $(c_n)$, but he'd run off letters, so he chose $(x_{ni})$ for each $M_i$. But what does it mean to define a sequence for each $n$, like he did in the beggining?

Also, am I right?

Comment: An arbitrary element of the product set $M$ *is* a sequence $(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_i,\dots)$ such that $s_i \in M_i$ for each $i$. In particular, for each $n = 1, 2, \dots$, the entry $x_n$ of the sequence is itself a sequence $((x_n)_1, (x_n)_2, \dots, (x_n)_i,\dots$; for simplicity of notation just write $x_{n\,i}$ instead of $(x_n)_i$.